# Connection Timeout Error: AWS-Glue ETL Job with Comprehend

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I am attempting to use a python template provided by AWS that I modified to load the yelp review dataset (LARGE JSON file) into an S3 bucket using glue, where I apply the comprehend API embedded within the python script.

I continue to receive an error message:

> ConnectTimeout:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='comprehend.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to comprehend.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>   timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

I have updated the original template to use json rather than parquet. Also, I have updated the number of batches within the original file from 10 to 1000 (where NUMBER_OF_BATCHES = 1000 in above script). Is there anything else I can do optimize my code so I stop receiving an error? Here is the existing code with existing s3 files paths to the VERY large JSON file I am trying to apply comprehend API:

```
import os
import sys
import boto3

from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row, Window, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "6000").getOrCreate()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("json.enable.summary-metadata", "false")

AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'
MIN_SENTENCE_LENGTH_IN_CHARS = 10
MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH_IN_CHARS = 4500
COMPREHEND_BATCH_SIZE = 25  ## This is the max batch size for comprehend
NUMBER_OF_BATCHES = 1000

SentimentRow = Row("review_id", "sentiment")
def getBatchSentiment(input_list):
  arr = []
  bodies = [i[1] for i in input_list]
  client = boto3.client('comprehend',region_name = AWS_REGION)

  def callApi(text_list):
    response = client.batch_detect_sentiment(TextList = text_list, LanguageCode = 'en')
    return response

  for i in range(NUMBER_OF_BATCHES-1):
    text_list = bodies[COMPREHEND_BATCH_SIZE * i : COMPREHEND_BATCH_SIZE * (i+1)]
    response = callApi(text_list)
    for r in response['ResultList']:
      idx = COMPREHEND_BATCH_SIZE * i + r['Index']
      arr.append(SentimentRow(input_list[idx][0], r['Sentiment']))

  return arr

### Main function to process data through comprehend

## Read yelp academic dataset reviews
reviews = spark.read.json("s3://schmldemobucket/yelp_academic_dataset_review.json").distinct()

df = reviews \
  .withColumn('body_len', F.length('text')) \
  .filter(F.col('body_len') > MIN_SENTENCE_LENGTH_IN_CHARS) \
  .filter(F.col('body_len') < MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH_IN_CHARS) 

record_count = df.count()

df2 = df \
  .repartition(record_count / (NUMBER_OF_BATCHES * COMPREHEND_BATCH_SIZE)) \
  .sortWithinPartitions(['review_id'], ascending=True)

group_rdd = df2.rdd.map(lambda l: (l.review_id, l.text)).glom()
sentiment = group_rdd.coalesce(10).map(lambda l: getBatchSentiment(l)).flatMap(lambda x: x).toDF().repartition('review_id').cache()

## Join sentiment results with the yelp review dataset
joined = reviews \
  .drop('text') \
  .join(sentiment, sentiment.review_id == reviews.review_id) \
  .drop(sentiment.review_id)

## Write out result set to S3 in JSON format
joined.write.partitionBy('business_id').mode('overwrite').json('s3://schmldemobucket/')

job.commit()
```

I expect to receive a successful glue etl job status but I'm not sure how to optimize further to receive a succeeded job status. Please help!!!!